# in magento2 wholesale account creation form in email field add customer group validation

Tags: magento2, javascript, form-validation

i want to add validation for email field in wholesale account creation form that the same email id which is used for retailer account can also be used for wholesale account so basically i want to add validation to check the customer group if the customer is wholesale it should not allow same email-id but it is different then wholesale like retailer then it should allow currently i have this module for wholesale module-company

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
'use strict';
return function (target) {

    /**
     * @param {*} value
     * @param {HTMLElement} element
     * @return {*|jQuery}
     */
    var asyncValidate = function (value, element) {
        return $(element).data('async-is-valid');
    };

    $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-async-company-email',
        asyncValidate,
        $.mage.__('Company with this email address already exists in the system. Enter a different email address to continue.') //eslint-disable-line max-len
    );

    $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-async-company-role-name',
        asyncValidate,
        $.mage.__('User role with this name already exists. Enter a different name to save this role.')
    );

    $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-async-customer-email',
        asyncValidate,
        $.mage.__('User with this email already exists in the system. Enter a different email address to continue. If you want to use your current account as an administrator account, please contact the seller.') //eslint-disable-line max-len
    );

    return target;
};
});
```

currently this is used for email validation

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-async-customer-email',
        asyncValidate,
        $.mage.__('User with this email already exists in the system. Enter a different email address to continue. If you want to use your current account as an administrator account, please contact the seller.') //eslint-disable-line max-len
    );
```

so now i want to add validation for customer group

thanks